# Integrating an .app inside UIViewcontroller of another app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, admob

currently I'm using an external program (Stencyl) to build my app, however I can't integrate AdMob to it. I thought I might be able to integrate my app (or xcode project) into the AdMob xcode project. Is there a way to do this? Is it even possible?

To clarify:

I got the AdMob working in XCode, I want to add an app/xcodeproject inside my AdMob's xcodeproj main window.

Comment: It does not seem to be plausible if you do not have the source code for Stencyl.

Comment: Hey Zhang, thanks for the fast response. I don't have the source code for Stencyl, however I do have the xcodeproject (Stencyl exports the game to XCode using Haxe, so basically, I have a bunch of files in XCode that are in .hx and compiled through Haxe when XCode runs)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is reference one project inside another, you can do this by dragging the project file (the .xcodeproj) from a Finder window into your AdMob XCode workspace. Make sure both projects are not open at once though.

Comment: Hi RajPara, I've already done that, however I'm not sure how to make project A appear in the window of project B. Is there a way to build some kind of "layers" ? i.e. Layer 0 has the AdMob Banner and it's the main window, and Layer 1 has the application, they don't need to interact, just be one on top of the other